# Add model error message to unique index with partial view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, frameworks, entity

I have list of model that is created by partial view so every row gets an index of unique id.

I want in the post of this form to add model error to fields in the list. But the unique id doesn't get in the controller so, i can not specify the key of the validation message to the field

Can any one help?

Update With code:

View with the form

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Socio", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" ,@class= "SpForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <div id="Studfindiv">
            @foreach (var StudFin in Model.ListStudentFinances)
            {
                @Html.Partial("StudFinView", StudFin)
            }
        </div>

}
```

Partial View that has the validation message for:

```
@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem
@model DataEntities.StudentFinance

    <div class="studfin">
        @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ListStudentFinances"))
        {
            <div class="text-center">
                <h3><span class="box-title"></span> מס' @(Model.FinNo + 1)</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center my-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, ViewBag.YearsList as SelectList, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "must control-label chosen", @data_placeholder = "שנה" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-center my-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month, ViewBag.MonthsList as SelectList, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "must control-label chosen", @data_placeholder = "חודש" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Month, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Month, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-row text-center w-75 mx-auto">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "must control-label pos-num" } })
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "title" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <p>קובץ <span class="box-title"></span></p>
            <div class="half-row">
                <div class="form-row chose-file-warp">
                    <div class="chose-file text-center">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FileSalary, new { @class = "must control-label", @type = "file", @accept = "image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png,application/pdf", @style = "display:none;", @path = Model.PathSalary })
                        <label for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.FileSalary)">
                            <i class="ml-1 material-icons">add_photo_alternate</i>
                            בחר קובץ
                        </label>
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("Salary1", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center form-row ">
                    <a name="@Model.PathSalary" style="display:@(Model.PathSalary != null ? "" : "none")" class="btn btn-light btn-file">צפייה בקובץ שמור</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FinNo)
        }
    </div>
```

And the controller that adds the validation message on post action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Student")]
public ActionResult Socio(SocioAdd socio, string uploadmethod)
{

 foreach (var fin in socio.ListStudentFinances)
                {
                    //until last year
                    if (fin.Year < DateTime.Now.Year - 1 || fin.Year == 0)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Year", "שנה לא תקינה");
                        ok = false;
                    }
                    if (fin.Month > 12 && fin.Month < 1)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Month", "חודש לא תקין");
                        ok = false;
                    }
                    if (fin.Salary < 0)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Salary", "הכנסה לא תקינה");
                        ok = false; 
                    }
                    if (fin.FileSalary == null && fin.PathSalary == null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("FileSalary", "חובה לצרף קובץ");
                        ok = false;
                    }
}
```

The list has indexes that is created by the partial view in the client and to add model error i need to specify this id as in the picture.

[Keys of model state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UlTD.jpg)

Can any one could help me to add validation messages to this?

Comment: Could you add some code for better explanation? We would all benefit from it!

Comment: I have added could you try to help?